# Coding Bat Exercise TempConvert

Tags: java

You want to create a method that will convert temperatures from fahrenheit to centigrade and vice versa. You will be given two things. First, the current measurement of the temperature as a decimal. Second, the scale on which the current measurement is based. If the temperature is given in fahrenheit, the second variable will be an 'f'. Using the following equation, convert it to centigrade and return the value. C=(F-32)*(5/9). If the temperature is given in centigrade, the second variable will be a 'c'. Use the following equation to convert it to fahrenheit and return the value. F=(C*(9/5))+32.

TempConvert(100.0, 'c') → 212.0

TempConvert(0.0, 'c') → 32.0

TempConvert(22.0, 'c') → 71.6

I can't figure this out.. I need help!!!

```
public double TempConvert(double temp,char scale) {
    double cent=(faren-32)*(5/9);
    double faren=(cent*(9/5))+32;

    if (temp==faren)
        scale = 'f';
    else if (temp==cent)
        scale = 'c';
}
```

Any Ideas!! Please help!!

Comment: Why are you setting `scale` in the body? I thought `scale` was an input to determine whether `temp` was a value in F or C.

Comment: I am a beginner and kinda of got the idea from the web. I don't know what to do next. Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick way to handle it.

```
public double TempConvert(double temp,char scale) {
    if (scale=='c') // the current temp is in Celsius
        return ((temp*9)/5)+32; // fixed for order of operations
    if (scale=='f') // the current temp is in Fahrenheit
        return ((temp-32)*5)/9; // fixed for order of operations
    return -1; // incorrect char selected
}
```

**Edit - Simpler method.**

Since you are using doubles, your integers need to be doubles. Java sees 5/9 as integer 5 divided by integer 9. Changing them to 5.0 and 9.0, respectively, fixes that.

```
public double TempConvert(double temp,char scale) {
    if (scale=='c') 
        return (9.0/5.0)*temp+32;
    if (scale=='f')
        return (temp-32)*(5.0/9.0);
    return -1;
}
```